# Python/SQLAlchemy not updating instances with list of tuples

Tags: python, database, list, sqlalchemy, pickle

I've been learning to use SQLAlchemy and am trying to get it to load data already in the database, change values of the objects by adding a tuple to a list, then save/update them in the database.

For some reason, when I append a tuple to an attribute that is a list of tuples, the updater of SQLAlchemy ignores it. Using Session.dirty and re-querying the database shows no change has happened to that value.

How do I create or update an object attribute that is a list of tuples so that the database is updated, too?

Here's the code for the database:

```
class SQLAlchemyDatabase():

    def __init__(self, DBDirectory, ThisDatabaseName, Report=False):
        ''' Creating the database by path and name given '''

        self.Directory = DBDirectory
        self.DatabaseName = ThisDatabaseName

        # I can't remember why this was in my c++ code...
        # if the new directory should be in another folder,
        # add the backslash, otherwise keep it free of
        # backslashes to make it in the current folder
        if len(self.Directory) > 0:
            self.Directory = self.Directory + "\\"

        DatabasePath = self.Directory + self.DatabaseName

        print "Opening", DatabasePath

        EngineCommand = "sqlite:///"
        self.engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(EngineCommand+DatabasePath, echo=Report)
        self.Session = sessionmaker(bind=self.engine)
        self.Base = declarative_base()
        try:
            self.DB = self.Session()
        except Error as e:
            print "An error occurred in making the database at", DatabasePath, ":", e.args[0]

        self.Base.metadata.create_all(self.engine)

Statics = SQLAlchemyDatabase("", "Tester.db", True)
```

Here's the class code for the object:

```
class TestObj(Statics.Base):
    """ Objects that exist as a template for all base objects """
    __tablename__ = "TestObj"

    ID = Column(Text, primary_key=True) 
    ListOfTuples = Column(PickleType, primary_key=False) # List of dual int tuples
    Digit = Column(Integer, primary_key=False)


    def __init__(self,ID, ListOfTuples, Digit):

        # Unique Identifier
        self.ID = ID
        # List of paired int tuples
        self.ListOfTuples = ListOfTuples
        # Some other digit
        self.Digit = Digit

    def __repr__(self, ):
        return "<Material ('%s', '%s', '%s')>" % (self.ID, self.ListOfTuples, self.Digit)
```

Here's the code where I add, load, modify, and then check to see if the database updated:

```
print "Creating each TestObj"
TestObj1 = TestObj("M001", [], 0)
TestObj2 = TestObj("M002", [], 0)
TestObj3 = TestObj("M003", [], 0)

print "Creating the table in the DB"
Statics.Base.metadata.create_all(Statics.engine)
print "Adding each object to the table"
Statics.DB.add(TestObj1)
Statics.DB.add(TestObj2)
Statics.DB.add(TestObj3)

print "Querying the table for the objects"
ListOfObjects = Statics.DB.query(TestObj).all()
print ListOfObjects

print "Modifying the objects to test updating"
NewDigit = 1
for EachObject in ListOfObjects:
    print EachObject
    EachObject.ListOfTuples.append((1,2))
    EachObject.Digit = NewDigit
    NewDigit += 1
    print "Now the Object is:", EachObject

print "Seeing what is to be updated (should show all 3 objects with the ListOfTuples attribute for changing)"
print Statics.DB.dirty

print "Commit changes to DB"
print Statics.DB.commit()

print "Re-query the database to see what the values are now"
ListOfObjects2 = Statics.DB.query(TestObj).all()
print ListOfObjects
```

Comment: No ideas on what might be causing this problem? I have a suspicion it's somewhere in the way that I declare the ListOfTuples attribute:     ListOfTuples = Column(PickleType, primary_key=False) I think I'm not declaring a list right for SQLAlchemt, but Pickling it seems like a right way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Python objects and collections that are being persisted as a scalar value to a column, such as a Python list that you're persisting as a pickled string,  do not by themselves report in-place changes to the ORM.  To get this behavior, it's something that you have to implement yourself using the [mutable extension](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/extensions/mutable.html), where you'd create a list subclass that reports on change events.

Another way to deal with a scalar-persisted collection is to replace with a new one instead of mutating in place, such as `myobject.list_of_tuples = myobject.list_of_tuples + [('new')]`.  An assignment to the column-mapped attribute is always picked up as a change event without any extra work.